# How to stream music to a PC?

Tags: itunes, audio, windows, macos, airplay

How do I use my Mac to stream audio (preferably using AirPlay) over WiFi to my 2 PCs with sound systems?  (If at the same time, then they need to be in perfect sync)

It would also be nice to be able to clone the display, but that is a very far second in priority.

These machines are on a network with no internet access, but the Mac is on a second network with internet access (do not want to bridge the networks - out of the question).  I'd like to be able to control the audio playing through the PC with the Mac.  I know AirPlay supports stuff like this, but I need to figure out how to get an AirPlay receiver running on my PC.  Even a VM of a standalone receiver would work...

Mac version OS X 10.11 El Capitan
Windows version Windows 7 Home Premium
Windows version Windows XP Professional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out which program works!  5KPlayer http://www.5kplayer.com/airplay/

It will work with Windows 7 and newer, haven't tried it with Vista or older, but I suspect it would work at least back to Vista 64 bit.

It's a simple install and setup, and it's totally free!

EDIT:  I have tested it with Windowx XP Professional 32 bit.  It works wonderfully without any problems at all.  I suspect it would work all the way back to 95 if you could get the .Net framework running there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install iTunes on both computers
2. Sign in to Home Sharing on both using the same AppleID (it doesn't have to be the same AppleID as you use for store purchases)
3. Leave iTunes running on both.
4. Follow the help on the PC to select the Mac's music library and stream away.

Since you have added a lot of extra requirements to your question, I would just set up a Home Stereo system and have the playing computer use bluetooth or a cable connection to input sound to the amplifier/receiver. I use a belkin unit, but there are many at inexpensive prices and then you can use an iOS device to remote control the selected iTunes instance.

- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00B9NATUI/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B9NATUI) - XtremeMac Bluetooth Connect Audio Receiver

Comment: OK, just FYI, these machines are on a network without internet access.  Edit made to question.

Comment: @Daniel You could connect them long enough to establish authenticated keys at which point the sharing would still work locally without an ongoing network connection.

Comment: I can't connect them to the internet at all (parental deal)

Comment: Bummer - your setup goes out of the way to make this highly complicated. Apple has solved this issue and even supports you on AppleCare if you use their engineering. I can't see you getting anything working that's always in sync unless you set up a single "DLNA type server" and give up on the "shared, synced, but totally independent copies of the same library" requirement.

Comment: I know, but it's not my fault I'm a high schooler with no budget for a Mac!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for free using VLC.  VLC can broadcast streams of audio and video to your local network.  The best part, it is completely free.

[VLC Streaming HowTo](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo_New/)

Comment: That would work but I have to initiate the connection from my PC.  not the idea.

Comment: You wouldn't have it initiate a connection.  VLC (on the mac) can be configured to stream audio/video (broadcast) from any source and all your PC's would have to do is listen with another VLC client.  VLC has a cli (command line interface) that you can use to automate this entire process via script (startup) or event (scheduled).

Comment: The VLC instance on the Mac can be likened to a server/daemon/whatever.  The VLC instance on the PC can be likened to a client.  The client must connect to the server, since I can't have the PC's VLC instance constantly trying to connect to the Mac, since that would not only be inefficient, but also impractical, since the Mac is not always on/streaming/connected.  Also, I'd have to open up the Mac's firewall.  Not happy with that.  With my solution (see below) I don't have to jump through any hoop, and it works with iOS devices as well.  That's a very nice benefit.  It also works with Apple TV

Comment: if I want it to.  http://www.5kplayer.com